# Entity Framework Core - PersistKeysToDbContext mysql issue

Tags: mysql, entity-framework-core

using Entity Framework Core I want to PersistKeysToDbContext.
my code in startup.cs

```
 services.AddDbContext<DataProtectionKeysContext>(options =>
                    options.UseMySql(this.Configuration.GetMySQLConnectionString("ConnectionOptions:XXX")))
                .AddDataProtection()
                .PersistKeysToDbContext<DataProtectionKeysContext>();
```

At the run time I am getting follwoing exception 
**An error occurred while trying to encrypt the provided data. Refer to the inner exception for more information.**
The exception source is Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection 
inner exception is : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
stack trace is 
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.KeyRingBasedDataProtector.Protect(Byte[] plaintext)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.SecureDataFormat`1.Protect(TData data, String purpose) at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.SecureDataFormat`1.Protect(TData data)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.WriteNonceCookie(String nonce)
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.d__19.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectHandler.d__18.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.d__54.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.d__14.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.d__5.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at QQQ.WebApplication.Startup.<>c.<b__5_0>d.MoveNext() in E:\project\QQQ\Development\Sites\QQQ.WebApplication\Startup.cs:line 420
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.d__6.MoveNext()
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at XXX.Core.Middleware.SecurityHeaders.SecurityHeadersMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext() in E:\project\QQQ\Development\Common\XXX.Core\Middleware\SecurityHeaders\SecurityHeadersMiddleware.cs:line 62
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
at XXX.Core.Middleware.ExceptionMiddleware.d__3.MoveNext() in E:\project\QQQ\Development\Common\XXX.Core\Middleware\ExceptionMiddleware.cs:line 51